# Python and SQL - inserting and reading values

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, window

I have a problem with my code. I'm making a windowed application. Right now, I need to insert data to table in database and then show it to me (with SELECT). I have 2 fields to input the Name and Password for user (ID is calculated based on number of entries in the table) and a button to trigger the input. Then I have a field where I would like to have something like confirmation to be displayed after insert, and a button to trigger "SELECT" from the table. The application does start, but as far as I can tell, it doesn't add that to the table (and doesn't display anything as a confirmation). Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3 as lite
import sys
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

con = None
con = lite.connect('test.db')
cur = con.cursor() 


class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super(Application, self).__init__(master)  
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.inst_lbl = Label(self, text = "Dodaj uzytkownika")
        self.inst_lbl.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)

        self.pwa = Label(self, text = "Login")
        self.pwa.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)

        self.pwb = Label(self, text = "Haslo")
        self.pwb.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)


        self.a = Entry(self)
        self.a.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = W)
        self.b = Entry(self)
        self.b.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky = W)




        self.submit_bttn = Button(self, text = "Dodaj uzytkownika", command = self.dodaj)
        self.submit_bttn.grid(row = 3, column = 0, sticky = W)

        self.secret_txt = Text(self, width = 35, height = 5, wrap = WORD)
        self.secret_txt.grid(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)

        self.view_users = Button(self, text = "Wyswietl uzytkownikow", command = self.wyswietl)
        self.view_users.grid(row = 10, column = 0, sticky = W)

        self.users_window = Text(self, width = 35, height = 5, wrap = WORD)
        self.users_window.grid(row = 11, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)

    def dodaj(self):
        a = self.a.get()
        b = self.b.get()
        index = cur.execute("SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM users")
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO users (Id, Nazwa, Haslo) VALUES(?,?,?)", (int(index),str(a),str(b)))
        #obj = AES.new('This is a key123', AES.MODE_CBC, 'This is an IV456')
        #ciphertext = obj.encrypt(test)
        self.secret_txt.delete(0.0, END)
        self.secret_txt.insert(0.0, (index, a, b))
    def wyswietl(self):
        viewall = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
        self.users_window.delete(0.0, END)
        self.users_window.insert(0.0, viewall)



root = Tk()
root.title("ShopQIP")
root.geometry("1024x700")
#root.mainloop()

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

And when I try to view the contents of the table, I get the error in that field:
 
*sqlite3.Cursor object at 0x02A6E220*

Also, the code runs, but I get this error when running it:
 
*Exception in Tkinter callback
 
Traceback (most recent call last):
 
  File "C:\Users\kjubus\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1549, in **call** 
    return self.func(*args)
 
  File "C:\Users\kjubus\Dysk Google!Szkoła\MGR\Projekt inzynierski\inzynierka v0.1.py", line 52, in dodaj
 
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO users (Id, Nazwa,Haslo) VALUES(?,?,?)", (int(index),str(a),str(b)))
 
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'sqlite3.Cursor'*
 
and just to clarify - in this part "line 1549" call before and after **call** there are 2 underscores.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`__call__` is an internal method used to call objects and functions. You can probably ignore that.

A cursor's `execute` method normally returns some innocuous value like the number of rows affected, and the results are returned by a separate call to one of its `fetch*` methods. So you probably need something like

```
    cur.execute("SELECT COUNT(Id) FROM users")
    index = cur.fetchone()[0] # First (and only) element in the single row
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO users (Id, Nazwa, Haslo) VALUES(?,?,?)", (int(index),str(a),str(b)))
```

Comment: It seems to work now (it shows the "confirmation" data in that field), but it doesn't seem to have any affect on the test.db file. Also, the second part (to view all entries) still doesn't work

Comment: That's probably because you haven't called the `commit` method of the database connection from which you created the cursor. This is needed to make the changes permanent

Comment: yes, I've just added 
    con.commit()
and it works. But I can't get the "select" part to work. any idea?

Comment: It's the same problem - you assume that `execute` returns the result of the query, which it doesn't. Replace `viewall = cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users")` with `cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users")` and then insert a line reading `viewall = cur.fetchall()`